# When authenticating requests to the Twitter API v2 endpoints

Tags: twitter, twitter-api-v2

I am encountering a notification while authenticating requests to the Twitter API v2 endpoints.

```
{
  client_id: 'xxxxxxx',
  detail: 'When authenticating requests to the Twitter API v2 endpoints, you must use keys and tokens from a Twitter developer App that is attached to a Project. You can create a project via the developer portal.',
  registration_url: 'https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/projects/overview',
  title: 'Client Forbidden',
  required_enrollment: 'Appropriate Level of API Access',
  reason: 'client-not-enrolled',
  type: 'https://api.twitter.com/2/problems/client-forbidden'
}
```

I am using the free tier. Please guide me on how to resolve this!
I use the code [snippet here](https://github.com/leerob/leerob.io/blob/main/lib/twitter.ts).

Answer (score 7):

As documented in this [latest summary of Twitter API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/getting-started/about-twitter-api) the Free tier doesn't allow fetching tweets which seems to be what you are trying to do.

You'll need at least the Basic access tier which isn't free. You can subscribe to it in your Dashboard in the Developer Portal i.e. https://developer.twitter.com/en/portal/dashboard

You need to have a Project and your app should be in that Project. The app should only use the V2 API for everything except media upload and the v1.1 Oauth as other v1.1 APIs are no longer available.

It's worth having a look at the [latest announcements on the Twitter Developer Forum](https://twittercommunity.com/c/announcements/22) so that you are up-to-date with the current requirements for consuming Twitter APIs.

Also the forum is currently flooding with questions about migrating to the latest tiers, the V2 API and dealing with the technical glitches that seem to occur on Twitter developer accounts, so for many issues there may already be solutions or at least useful hints. The Twitter Developer Forum main page: https://twittercommunity.com/

Comment: Due to the major changes at Twitter this spring and summer I'd suggest that questions regarding Twitter APIs would contain the following information: 1) Has the OP already migrated to the new access tiers and V2 API 2) If yes, did their app already work at some point 3) What's their app's status in the Dashboard as there have been many cases of apps being suspended or suddenly moving from a Project to a Standalone app. These are all relevant details and having to ask them all separately delays getting and answer to the OP's problem.

Comment: Twitter now charges $100 for their basic plan. What a joke.